# Probability value

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

So i've a quit question about a Probability value.
I have two below values:

```
a = 2 and b = 3.
```

My question is to know how can i find the probability of a greater than b?
Both are using Triangular Distribution.
    Prob = Pr(a > b ).

Thanks

Comment: As written, it sounds like `a` and `b` are just numbers, in which case `Pr(2 > 3)=0` but I don't think that's what you mean.  Are `a` and `b` drawn from probability distributions?  Do you know anything about those distributions?

Comment: Yes sorry, the distributions are triangular distribution.

Comment: Please include that information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dista = TriangularDistribution[];

distb = TriangularDistribution[];

Probability[a > b, {a \[Distributed] dista, b \[Distributed] distb}]

(* 1/2 *)

dista = TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}];

distb = TriangularDistribution[{1/2, 3/2}];

Probability[a > b, {a \[Distributed] dista, b \[Distributed] distb}]

(* 1/24 *)

dista = TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}];

distb = TriangularDistribution[{0, bmax}];

Probability[a > b, {a \[Distributed] dista, b \[Distributed] distb}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear BobThank you for your kind assistance